# Communications links failure

Tags: java, mysql, macos, mamp

I'm using a MacBook Pro with MAMP installed on it. Everything on the MAMP side is working fine. Also JDBC connector is in it's place.

The problem is that when I try to connect to MySQL through my java code it gives me the following error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:348)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2391)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at DatabaseConnection.<init>(DatabaseConnection.java:22)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
... 16 more
```

And here is my connection statement in my Java code(I checked the credentials as well):

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///"+databaseName, userName, password);
```

This totally drives me crazy because with the same installation and code on my iMac everything works fine.

So what is wrong on my MacBook Pro that's not letting me to connect to MySQL through Java?

Comment: Did you try to use the fully qualified url like: `jdbc:mysql://" + url + ":" + port + "/" + databaseName` instead of using the all default `jdbc:mysql:///"+databaseName` to see if you are getting the same result?

Comment: Verify that mysql is up and running and that you can connect to it. I know nothing of how MAMP installs and configures the server-software. But it looks like you can't connect to the mysql db the way you are trying to. (execute `mysql` and/or `telnet localhost 3306` could be a start, MAMP also ought to have some installation-verifying php-page (A hello world for example))

Comment: @evanwong Could you please give me the exact piece of code. I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do some diagnostics on the MacBook first.
Because the driver is not receiving any packets...
That means there's no connectivity.

Open up a terminal window and do:

```
su
--> enter password
mysql
--> does mysql start?
telnet localhost 3306
--> do you get a response?
ps -ef |grep mysql
--> do you see a mysql instance?
less /etc/my.cnf
--> check out the settings, what port number is used?
```

Comment: If a write mysql into the command line it gives me the 'command not found' error. But if I write this into the command line instead, /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot, I'm able to command MySQL from the command line.

Comment: Same issue. Can do this from command line but my IDE (in this case PHPStorm) gives the communications link error.

Comment: ps -ef saved me! Here was the service instance running in port 3307. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the MAMP, mysql J Connector, Java and "Communications link failure" exception was best resolved by installing a brand new copy of mysql Server.

I think by default MAMP version of mysql has the TCP/IP port turned off. You can turn it on by running the steps below. I found however that none of these steps worked for me and that it was much easier installing a brand new copy of mysql server which through the default install has network connections working.

You can try getting network access for MAMP mysql working with the following steps. Launch "MAMP Pro" (none of these functions are available in the free version)":

a. Go into menu "File"->"Edit Template"->"MySQL my.cnf" and editing the following 2 lines. Becareful not to change anything else.

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP
```

b. Uncheck the "Allow local access only" on the "Server" tab.

After you take these steps run to confirm TCP/IP access:

netstat -tln | grep mysql

Answer (score 1):

Just open the MAMP and uncheck 'allow local access only'. as simple as that :D

Comment: thanks but I see that that option is only available for MAMP PRO. I'm using MAMP mate.

Comment: in this case you can comment out : skip-networking in your my.cnf file, you can find it in -> .. MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.conf . nce you done restart the mamp .